# Подскажите как правильно протестировать RestTemplate сервис

Tags: java, spring, junit, resttemplate

подскажите пожалуйста как протестировать метод doRequest()

```
public String doRequest() {
    final String apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/{accountKey}/{type}";
    return restTemplate.exchange(apiUrl, GET, httpEntity(), String.class, uriParts()).getBody();
}

private Map<String, String> uriParts() {
    return new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("accountKey", "sekretKey");
        put("type", "user");            
    }};
}

private HttpHeaders httpHeaders() {
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(AUTHORIZATION,"sekretToken");
    headers.set(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    return headers;
}

private HttpEntity<String> httpEntity() {
    return new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders());
}
```

Пробовал писать такой тест:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    public class ReceiveConnectUser {
        @Mock
        private RestTemplate restTemplateMock;;
        @InjectMocks
        private ConnectRequest connectRequest;

        @Test
        public void receiveUser(){
connectRequest.doRequest();
            verify(restTemplateMock).exchange(startsWith("http://localhost/{accountKey}/{type}"),
                    Mockito.<HttpMethod>any(),
                    Mockito.<HttpEntity<String>>any(),
                    Mockito.<Class<String>>any(),
                    Mockito.<Map<String,String>>any());
}
}
```

Но падает ошибка nullPointerException и я не понимаю в чем дело и как его проверить.

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
at ConnectRequest.httpHeaders(ConnectRequest.java)
at ConnectRequest.httpEntity(ConnectRequest.java)
at ConnectRequest.doRequest(ConnectRequest.java)
at ReceiveConnectUser$receiveConnectUser.receiveUseer(ReceiveConnectUser.java:10)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:515)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:105)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Простите, но без стек трейса и полного кода теста невозможно понять где и почему выбрасывается исключение...

Comment: сори. подправил